# Requesting databases with C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am wondering if the following code is an old approach for working with database. Or I can use more modern and productive approach?

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.EventLogPrinterConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("", con);

    string sql_com_sel = "";
    sql_com_sel = @"SELECT DISTINCT Users, Pages, Date FROM View_lastactiveUser WHERE (Date >= @ds AND Date <= @dp AND Pages > 0) ORDER BY Date";
    com.CommandText = sql_com_sel;
    com.Parameters.Clear();
    com.Parameters.Add("@ds", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ds;
    com.Parameters.Add("@dp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dp;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        users.Add(new UserDemo() { LastActivity = dr["Date"].ToString(), Pages = int.Parse(dr["Pages"].ToString()), User = dr["Users"].ToString() });
    }
    con.Close();
    return users;
}
```

Comment: It's the one I use, except I don't take 4 steps to initialize the `CommandText` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [LinqtoSQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) or [The ADO.NET Entity Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

There are also some other solutions like nHibernate, but the first to come nativly with .NET

Answer (score 2):

Using plain ADO.NET is still a very valid approach. Just make sure to wrap your disposable resources in `using` blocks. Like this:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.EventLogPrinterConnectionString))
using (IDbCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
{
    con.Open();
    var sql_com_sel = @"SELECT DISTINCT Users, Pages, Date FROM View_lastactiveUser WHERE (Date >= @ds AND Date <= @dp AND Pages > 0) ORDER BY Date";
    com.CommandText = sql_com_sel;
    com.Parameters.Add("@ds", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ds;
    com.Parameters.Add("@dp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dp;
    using (IDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            users.Add(new UserDemo() { LastActivity = dr["Date"].ToString(), Pages = int.Parse(dr["Pages"].ToString()), User = dr["Users"].ToString() });
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

Of course you could also use an ORM framework such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) or Entity Framework. Or something lighter such as [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Answer (score 1):

while such code is acceptable, I highly suggest you to use LINQ to SQL, either the version provided by Microsoft, or the better one found at `http://bltoolkit.net`, at the moment it has the fastest LINQ parser.

Forgot to mention, that in your if you don't filter the query' parameters from end-user your database will be very vulnerable for SQL injection attacks, especially if you are building a web-site.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not with vanilla ADO.NET. But a more generic approach is something like this:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ProviderName;

DbProviderFactory provider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

using (DbConnection cn = provider.CreateConnection())
{
    cn.ConnectionString = connectionString

    using (DbCommand command = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "GetAllCustomers";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cn.Open();

        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Do Something...
        }
    }
}
```

See? No specific ADO.NET driver anywhere. [Read more here](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/08/CreatingDataAccessLayerUsingDbProviderFactoriesDbProviderFactory.aspx).

**Modern alternatives**

The more modern approach is to use a OR/M framework such as [entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) or [nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx). There are also more lightweight layers such as [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)